# Python regex print string within brackets without the bracket

Tags: python, regex

I have a string s:

```
s = '<xx></xx><xx><a>b<c>d<e>f</xx><xx>g</xx>'
```

How can I find the strings b, d and f? I have tried this:

```
import re
pattern = '(?<=>)([^<]+)(?=<)'
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Which also returns g:

```
['b', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

This pattern returns a blank list:

```
pattern = '<xx></xx><xx(?<=>)([^<]+)(?=<)/xx><xx>g</xx>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your pattern to

```
(?<=>)([^<]+)(?=<)(?=.*>[^<]+<)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/181)